# Add a new day column to dataframe based on datetime

Tags: pandas

I have a `dataframe` `dfr` that looks like this:

```
    symbol  eps epsEstimated    time    revenue revenueEstimated    updatedFromDate fiscalDateEnding
date                                
2023-02-02  AAPL    1.880000    1.9300  amc 117154000000    1.220540e+11    2023-01-25  2022-12-31
2022-10-27  AAPL    1.290000    1.2700  amc 90146000000 0.000000e+00    2022-10-26  2022-09-24
...
```

I want to create three new `columns` `year, month, day`:

```
dfr.dtypes

date                datetime64[ns]
symbol                      object
eps                        float64
epsEstimated               float64
time                        object
revenue                      int64
revenueEstimated           float64
updatedFromDate             object
fiscalDateEnding            object
dtype: object
```

This doesn't work:

```
dfr['day'] = dfr.index.day
dfr['month'] = dfr.index.month
dfr['year'] = dfr.index.year

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[31], line 1
----> 1 dfr['day'] = dfr.index.day
      2 dfr['month'] = dfr.index.month
      3 dfr['year'] = dfr.index.year

AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'day'
```

At the end I want `dfr` to contain three new columns, where the `year/month/day` `columns` corresponds to the `index` (`date`) at that `row`?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" - what's the full traceback? Is your index actually a datetime like object... what does `dfr.index.dtype` tell you?

Comment: That error doesn't make sense given your example DF...

Comment: See new edits to OP

Comment: So `date` isn't your index... use `dfr['day'] = dfr['date'].dt.day` etc....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index).year
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index).month
df['day'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index).day
```

outcome:

```
           symbol   eps  epsEstimated time       revenue  revenueEstimated  \
2023-02-02   AAPL  1.88          1.93  amc  117154000000      1.220540e+11   
2022-10-27   AAPL  1.29          1.27  amc   90146000000      0.000000e+00   

           updatedFromDate fiscalDateEnding  year  month  day  
2023-02-02      2023-01-25       2022-12-31  2023      2    2  
2022-10-27      2022-10-26       2022-09-24  2022     10   27
```